# Scrapy spider logs the text I need (works in scrapy shell too) but doesn't write them in JSON file

Tags: python, scrapy

I am fairly new to `scrapy`. I'm trying to scrape the reviews from this page: https://utopia.de/produkt/j-j-darboven-cafe-intencion/ so I created this spider:

```
import scrapy

class UtopiaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'utopia'
    allowed_domains = ['utopia.de']
    start_urls = ['https://utopia.de/produkt/j-j-darboven-cafe-intencion/']
    def parse(self, response):
        self.log("I just visited: " + response.url)
        reviews = response.css('div.commenttext p:nth-child(1)::text').extract()
        self.log(reviews)
        yield
        {
        "review":reviews
        }
```

When I tried scraping the reviews in the `scrapy shell` with this code:

```
scrapy shell https://utopia.de/produkt/j-j-darboven-cafe-intencion/
In [1]:  response.css('div.commenttext p:nth-child(1)::text').extract()
```

I was able to see the reviews:

```
Out[1]:
['Wir haben für unseren Vollautomaten wirklich lange probiert, und kommen immer wieder zu diesem. Die Bohnen sind alle ganz und nicht zu dunkel, also nicht billig überröstet. Der Geschmack ist wirklich super ohne bittere Note. Im Rewe gibt es immer mal wieder Sonderangebote der Marke, da kann man bis zu 3 € pro Packung sparen. Hier greifen wir dann immer zu. Der Kaffee lässt Genuss zu ohne schlechtes Gewissen.',
 'Der Kaffee ist große Klasse, da gibt es nachwievor nix zu meckern dran. Aber Inhalt ist nicht alles. Die letzte Verpackung hat in der Papierhülle jetzt Plastik mit reingemischt. Ich frag mich, wozu das gut sein soll. Für mich ein Grund zum Punkteabzug.',
 'Ich kehre seit Jahren nach Ausflügen zu anderen Kaffeesorten immer wieder zu diesem zurück, weil er mir am besten schmeckt. Ich mag Kaffee am liebsten mit einer „normalen“ Kaffeemaschine gekocht und nicht sehr stark. Dafür ist er super. Er ist nicht sehr stark geröstet und hat einen schönen Mokkageschmack.',
 'Bereits seit sechs Jahren beginne ich den Tag mit diesem Kaffee, und er schafft es täglich aufs Neue, mich zu begeistern. Ich konsumiere ausschließlich fair produzierten Kaffee, um mit einem guten Gewissen in den Alltag starten zu können. Meine Wahl wird weiterhin auf diesen fallen. �']
```

I am also able to log the reviews with `self.log(reviews)` line in my spider

```
2019-11-06 15:44:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://utopia.de/produkt/j-j-darboven-cafe-intencion/> (referer: None)
2019-11-06 15:44:06 [utopia] DEBUG: I just visited: https://utopia.de/produkt/j-j-darboven-cafe-intencion/
2019-11-06 15:44:06 [utopia] DEBUG: Wir haben für unseren Vollautomaten wirklich lange probiert, und kommen immer wieder zu diesem. Die Bohnen sind alle ganz und nicht zu dunkel, also nicht billig überröstet. Der Geschmack ist wirklich super ohne bittere Note. Im Rewe gibt es immer mal wieder Sonderangebote der Marke, da kann man bis zu 3 € pro Packung sparen. Hier greifen wir dann immer zu. Der Kaffee lässt Genuss zu ohne schlechtes Gewissen.
2019-11-06 15:44:06 [utopia] DEBUG: Der Kaffee ist große Klasse, da gibt es nachwievor nix zu meckern dran. Aber Inhalt ist nicht alles. Die letzte Verpackung hat in der Papierhülle jetzt Plastik mit reingemischt. Ich frag mich, wozu das gut sein soll. Für mich ein Grund zum Punkteabzug.
2019-11-06 15:44:06 [utopia] DEBUG: Ich kehre seit Jahren nach Ausflügen zu anderen Kaffeesorten immer wieder zu diesem zurück, weil er mir am besten schmeckt. Ich mag Kaffee am liebsten mit einer „normalen“ Kaffeemaschine gekocht und nicht sehr stark. Dafür ist er super. Er ist nicht sehr stark geröstet und hat einen schönen Mokkageschmack.
2019-11-06 15:44:06 [utopia] DEBUG: Bereits seit sechs Jahren beginne ich den Tag mit diesem Kaffee, und er schafft es täglich aufs Neue, mich zu begeistern. Ich konsumiere ausschließlich fair produzierten Kaffee, um mit einem guten Gewissen in den Alltag starten zu können. Meine Wahl wird weiterhin auf diesen fallen. �
2019-11-06 15:44:06 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

But the `yield` part of my spider doesn't seem to work because when I run this command, I end up with an empty `JSON` file:

```
scrapy runspider utopia.py -o utopia.json
```

I have a hunch that the reviews are displayed with Javascript, but I'm confused as to why the text is still logged properly but can't be returned in the JSON file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a syntax mistake, try to update your code as follows:

```
yield {
    "review": reviews
}
```

Because there is nothing in front of your `yield`, basically what you are doing is `yield None`, this is why your json file is empty.